# Java: RandomStringUtils Random seed

Tags: java, random, apache-commons

I've been using `RandomStringUtils` to generate random IDs to be used as database keys:

```java
import org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils;
public class RandomStringTest {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            final String id = RandomStringUtils.random(8,
                    "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
            System.out.println(id);
        }
    }
}
```

The key space is large enough,

```
len("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")^8 = 2821109907456 ≃ 10^12
```

**Is the random mechanism properly seeded?** I need to know that the keys are properly distributed before applying this to production.

By the way, the test code showed no repetitions when executed a few times, but that's far from solid proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no seed provided in the implementation [I found](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html#line.282), there is just a `new Random()`. But there is a [method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html#random-int-int-int-boolean-boolean-char:A-java.util.Random-) where you can supply your own source of randomness

```
random(int count, int start, int end, 
        boolean letters, boolean numbers, 
        char[] chars, java.util.Random random)
```

Comment: For anyone who wants to generate strings that are difficult to predict, pass in a [java.security.SecureRandom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html).

Comment: What is the "default" randomness source? Is this source shared with other "Random" utilities? Does the `Random` instance I explicitly pass get used by further calls to `RandomStringUtils.*`? The documentation for this module is terrible :-(

Comment: A static `new Random();` is used if you don't pass a random yourself. All other methods seem to end up using the method in the answer eventually, using the static random. If you pass your own random, this is not stored and thus not used in further calls. There is one more 'random'-utility in this package (RandomUtils), they do not share code.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a random generator to generate unique keys. Nothing guarantees uniqueness. Why don't you use a UUID generator instead, or a database sequence?

And why do you want your keys to be properly distributed? The only important thing for a primary key is its uniqueness. And the seed doesn't have any impact on the distribution, AFAIK.

Comment: Agreed. There are legacy constraints I have to deal with.

Comment: There is nothing here that is stopping from giving the same id twice.